# Configuration System Failed to Initialize

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, database-connection, connection-string

I'm new to Visual Studio and MySQL. I'm thinking if somebody can tell me what's wrong with this code.

app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<add key="ODBCDriver" value="Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=localhost;"/>
<add key="DataBaseDetails" value="Database=timekeeping;uid=root;pwd=admin;Option=3;"/>
<configSections>
<sectionGroup name="userSettings"
    type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0,    Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
 </sectionGroup>
 </configSections>
 </configuration>
```

There is an error stating **Configuration system failed to initialize**.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly is there a reason you're not using a ConnectionString instead of custom keys?

Secondly can't you just use an Appsettings section to define your keys?  Assuming you are looking them up in your code:

eg. like:

```
<configuration>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="MappingLibrary" value="Model.dll" />
        <add key="ServicesLibrary" value="Services.dll" />
    </appSettings>
```

or you might just be able to replace the appsettings with your userSettings element?

Answer (score 0):

This work for me.
 Make sure that your app.config or web.config **start with** the  tag inside the   tab e.g

and in your case you have not end the  tag

after that make sure taht  targate Framework property of your project must not be **client profile**

Answer (score 0):

My reason for this issue was incompatibility between **MySql.Data.dll** and .Net framework version. Once I found lates version of **MySql.Data.dll** for .NET 5, this issue gone. Prior to change dll I gave a try to various suggestions within and without config file, with no luck.